# Excel generating prices difference between two sheets

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a `*.xlsx` file that contains the following two sheets:

sheet1:

[image]

sheet2:

[image]

How can I generate a third sheet that looks like this:

sheet3:

[image]

`B2` in sheet3 is -1 because 54 - 55 = -1.

`B3` in sheet3 is 67 because 67 - 0 = 67. (Sheet2 doesn't have `Banana` item so its price of banana is set to 0).

Comment: Is your data in tables, or should I use cell references for a solution?

Comment: My data are not in tables, you should use cell references for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be using `VLOOKUP()`. You can also use `INDEX/MATCH` or `XLOOKUP()` if you have <kbd>Excel O365</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$10,2,FALSE),0)-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$10,2,FALSE),0)
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, is it possible to automatically generate column A of sheet3?

Comment: I can use the "remove duplicates" button in excel to create column A.

Comment: @Brian If you have `Excel365` then it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

So the equation on sheet 3 has to be, `=sheet1!B2 - sheet2!B2` This will solve the problem. You can get more information on [Excel Formulas for Linking Data between Different Sheets](http://www.techlineinfo.com/excel-formulas-for-linking-data-between-different-sheets/)

I tried but It doesn't 100% solve your problem, `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:Sheet2!A10,1,FALSE)),Sheet1!B1,Sheet1!B1-Sheet2!B1)`

You might be able to get an idea.

Comment: No, `=sheet1!B2 - sheet2!B2`, `=sheet1!B3 - sheet2!B3`, `=sheet1!B4 - sheet2!B4` would create `-1`, `-2`, and `-51`, which are not the values I need.

Comment: The items in sheet1 and sheet2 are partially different.

Comment: @Brian I edited the code, but I'm sorry It doesn't exactly solve your problem. my bad. You might be able to get an idea from it.